# Use of silent letters and how to identify them?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letters, spelling-pronunciations

While watching SpellBee on Discovery Channel I came to hear the word *Malapropos* which was just pronounced without the ending *-s*, ie. it was silent.

The boy pronounced it correctly but missed the last *-s* and lost, But how come anyone will know that there will be a final *-s* just by hearing the pronunciation.

Is there any use of silent letters that makes them so important and how can we identify silent letters just by pronunciation?

Comment: French loanwords often have silent consonant letters, e.g. *chalet* where the letter t is silent.

Comment: 'Is there any use of silent letters that makes it so important?' I assume you mean 'Is there an underlying reason that makes using silent letters important?' @Mari-Lou has given one underlying reason; it's important because it's important to spell correctly (no matter how tedious learning the correct spellings may be). As for your second question, I think you realise that we can't. Years of practice and a  dictionary to hand.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Then its Spellbee's mistake

Comment: He pronounced the word without an -s, or he spelled it without an -s? Pronunciation is a different thing. Spelling bee competitions are hard for that reason, English spelling is not phonetic. Think of *corps* and *hyperbole* if you're seeing these words for the very first time, chances are you will mispronounce them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA He pronounced it without -s and if its so difficult how can a child get that

Comment: But it's spelled with an -s at the end. So the kid got the spelling wrong. Not everyone is good at spelling, the kid must have passed some regional rounds (I don't know, I never watch the competition) before reaching that stage. The word, malapropos, is in the English dictionary, it's not a neologism.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Can we identify a silent letter by seeing a new word?

Comment: Most dictionaries will include the phonetic pronunciation, but the best way is to hear a native speaker use it. But even native speakers get some words wrong, ask one speaker to spell "their" or "a lot" and some will spell it as "they're" and "allot". You see these misspellings all over the Internet. Sorry, but I don't have the time to stop and chat. I only replied out of politeness. Good luck with mastering the language! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78521/discussion-between-abhishek-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: You're just ignoring the person who took time to respond to you's last comment: 'Sorry, but I don't have the time to stop and chat. I only replied out of politeness.'  But my downvote is for the confirmation that this is a rant provided by your comment  'Then its Spellbee's mistake'. They're not allowed to ask any but the easiest of questions? Who says so?

Comment: "How can we identify silent letters just by pronunciation?" No. How could you? If everything were spelled exactly as it is pronounced, then there would be no point in spelling competitions in the first place  . . .

Comment: Also, would you argue that *two*, *too*, and *to* should be spelled identically only because they are pronounced identically? And, if so, which of the three spellings would you say it should be—and why?

Comment: The reason why there are spelling bees in the US is that spelling is particularly difficult. This is one of many reasons.

Comment: Since nobody else seems to have said this:  Nobody goes into a spelling bee having learned only a bunch of rules.  To get in the door, you must *memorize the **spellings*** of hundreds or thousands of words.  Somebody who knew only phonetic rules wouldn’t be able to spell simple words like ‘‘brought’’ and ‘‘caught’’.

Answer (score 2):

Spelling is generally not phonetic, as speaking and writing are not synchronised. At some point in the distant past they might have started out with a straight mapping, but if they did, they have since developed in different directions for a number of reasons. In some languages that is more pronounced than in others.

Why are they not kept in sync? Partly because there is nowadays a more or less standardised way of spelling, but there are many different ways of pronunciation (regional accents, or different national varieties in the case of English). Writing is less transient than speaking, and you don't want to constantly change the spelling of words, as it would make it harder to read older texts.

Silent letters are valuable as they give you an indication of a word's origin. For example, in English the initial *p* of *psychology* is silent. But if it was dropped from the spelling, then it would no longer be easily possible to link it to the Greek root (which is helpful in understanding the meaning of the word). And if you come across the German word *Psychologie*, you can probably guess what it means, even if you don't speak any German. This would not be the case if it was spelled "saikolodgy" in English.

So, silent letters (or irregular pronunciations) are valuable, and I'm afraid one just has to learn them as part of the language.

Comment: No, one has to learn them as part of learning **to spell** English. They're not part of the language; they're part of the technology that we use to record the language. And reading them is not difficult, once you realize they're spelled wrong. You don't have to remember how to spell them yourself, however, unless your career goals end at a spelling bee. If you misspell a word, most people won't notice, because they can't remember either. And everybody will recognize it anyway.